# import CSV without header row file to datatable

Tags: csv, datatable

I have a CSV file uploaded by UploadFile control which has no header row. When I try to read it to datatable it gives the error because the first row has same values in different columns. How to insert the header row to this file or read data from CSV to datatable with predefined columns?

```
Data in csv:
IO23968 2012    11  AB WI 100162804410W500  0   516.78  0   0   0   N   0   
IO24190 2012    11  AB WI 100140604510W500  302 516.78  15617.9 0   15617   N   0   
IO24107 2012    11  AB WI 100033104410W500  337 516.78  17456.3 0   17456   N   0   



Control:
HtmlInputFile fileOilFile = fileOilSubmission as HtmlInputFile;

        if (fileOilFile != null)
          strOilFileName = fileOilFile.Value;

DataTable:
DataTable csvData = new DataTable();
      csvData.Columns.Add("RoyaltyEntityID", typeof(string));
      csvData.Columns.Add("ProductionYear", typeof(int));
      csvData.Columns.Add("ProductionMonth", typeof(int));
      csvData.Columns.Add("ProductionEntityID", typeof(string));
      csvData.Columns.Add("ProductionVolume", typeof(double));
      csvData.Columns.Add("SalePrice", typeof(double));
      csvData.Columns.Add("GrossRoyaltyAmount", typeof(double));
      csvData.Columns.Add("TruckingRate", typeof(double));
      csvData.Columns.Add("TotalNetRoyalty", typeof(double));
      csvData.Columns.Add("ConfidentialWell", typeof(bool));
      csvData.Columns.Add("HoursProductionAmount", typeof(double));



using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(strOilFileName))
        {
          string s = String.Empty;
          while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
          { //we're just testing read speeds 

            foreach (var line in strOilFileName)
            {
              csvData.Rows.Add(line.split(',')[0]);
              csvData.Rows.Add(line.split(',')[1]);
              csvData.Rows.Add(line.split(',')[2]);
              csvData.Rows.Add(line.split(',')[3]);
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Which programming language are you using? What does your code look like so far?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just add the header manually in code then add the rows as you parse the file:

ex:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

foreach (var line in csv)
 {
      table.Rows.Add(line.split(',')[0]);
      table.Rows.Add(line.split(',')[1]);
      table.Rows.Add(line.split(',')[2]);
      table.Rows.Add(line.split(',')[3]);
 }
 return table;
```

Comment: Error 2 'char' does not contain a definition for 'split' and no extension method 'split' accepting a first argument of type 'char' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\SOURCE\IOGC\SEServices\uploadoilroyaltystatement.aspx.cs 439 31 IOGC

Comment: You have to get each line of the input file, if CSV was a line in a textreader the line variable in the for loop would be a string that would look like this: "1,Tylenol,Erin,04-20-2013" make sure it looks like that

Comment: Can you send the code you have for receiving the file? I can help you with the file parsing / datatable populating after that.

Comment: Just add the method that you use to recieve the file to your original Question (edit your questions and add the code block to it)

Comment: Once you recieve the file and its contents, use the following to iterate over each row and add it to the datatable:  using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fileName))
{
        string s = String.Empty;
        while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
               
        }
}

Comment: I tried...But again it is saying Split is not recognizable. I have updated my Q

Answer (score 0):

The code below shows how you might read a CSV into a DataTable.

This code assumes your CSV can be found at `strOilFileName` and the DataTable's schema is what you show in your question.  I'm also assuming that your CSV is actually comma-delimited (doesn't look that way from the sample data in your question).

```
DataTable csvData = new DataTable();
// ... add columns as you show.

using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(strOilFileName)) {
    string line = string.Empty;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
        string[] fields = line.Split(',');
        if (fields.Length == 13) {
            // Create a new empty row based on your DataTable's schema.
            var row = csvData.NewRow();

            //Start populating the new row with data from the CSV line.    
            row[0] = fields[0];

            // You can't be sure that the data in your CSV can be converted to your DataTable's column's data type so
            // always use the TryParse methods when you can.
            int prodYear = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(fields[1], out prodYear)) {
                row[1] = prodYear;
            } else {
                // Do what when the field's value does not contain a value that can be converted to an int?  
                // Here I'm setting the field to 2000 but you'll want to throw an Exception, set a different default, etc.
                row[1] = 2000;
            }
            //
            // Repeat the above steps for filling the rest of the columns in your DataRow.
            //

            // Add your new row to your DataTable.                        
            csvData.Rows.Add(row);
        } else {
            // Do something because Split returned in unexpected number of fields.
        }
    }
}
```

The code to read the CSV is fairly simplistic.  You might want to look into other CSV parsers that can handle a lot of the parsing details for you.  There are a bunch out there.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static DataTable GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(string csv_file_path)
    {
      DataTable csvData = new DataTable();
      csvData.Columns.Add("RoyaltyEntityID", typeof(string));
      csvData.Columns.Add("ProductionYear", typeof(int));
      csvData.Columns.Add("ProductionMonth", typeof(int));
      csvData.Columns.Add("ProductionEntityID", typeof(string));
      csvData.Columns.Add("ProductionVolume", typeof(double));
      csvData.Columns.Add("SalePrice", typeof(double));
      csvData.Columns.Add("GrossRoyaltyAmount", typeof(double));
      csvData.Columns.Add("TruckingRate", typeof(double));
      csvData.Columns.Add("TotalNetRoyalty", typeof(double));
      csvData.Columns.Add("ConfidentialWell", typeof(string));
      csvData.Columns.Add("HoursProductionAmount", typeof(double));

      using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(csv_file_path))
      {
        string line = string.Empty;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
          string[] strRow = line.Split(',');
          DataRow dr = csvData.NewRow();
          dr["RoyaltyEntityID"] = strRow[0];
          dr["ProductionYear"] = strRow[1];
          dr["ProductionMonth"] = strRow[2];
          dr["ProductionEntityID"] = strRow[3];
          dr["ProductionVolume"] = strRow[4];
          dr["SalePrice"] = strRow[5];
          dr["GrossRoyaltyAmount"] = strRow[6];
          dr["TruckingRate"] = strRow[7];
          dr["TotalNetRoyalty"] = strRow[8];
          dr["ConfidentialWell"] = strRow[9];
          if (strRow[9] == "Y")
          {
            dr["HoursProductionAmount"] = strRow[10];
          }
          else
          {
            dr["HoursProductionAmount"] = "0";
          }

          csvData.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
      }

  return csvData;
```

}`enter code here`